# How to restore a local database from central database

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, database-restore

I have multiple clients running SQL Server express and 1 central server running SQL Server enterprise. I want to sync the local databases to central which I can do using Microsoft sync framework. Let's say, one of the local machines crashed and I wish to restore the data from central server. How can I do it? Note: Data in different clients are different so there has to be data segregation. I can't restore all of my central server to local client. I want to restore just the local's data. To achieve this, using Microsoft sync is not an option because the central server doesn't keep track of from which local site the data is coming. Ultimately I want to achieve local servers syncing with central server and central server restoring local servers on failure.

Comment: why dont you add a client id for your data coming from the client? then create a filtered scope based on the clientid?

Comment: That was an option but according to business need the database schema in clients and servers should be the same. Hence, if I have a clientID column in server.. I am bound to have it on client which is useless. It is just bad design

Comment: why would it be useless? you use it to identify where the data came from. imho, it's an even worst design to be synchronizing data without being able to identify where they came from.

Comment: It would be useless in client side.. Having a column where data is irrelevant doesn't make any sense. I agree that it will make sense in the server side but the same schema has to be mimicked in client side. So I will end up having a clientID column in client server as well and this holds for every table that I want to sync

Comment: schema doesn't have to be the same. it's not that hard to inject a client id dynamically during sync. with or without sync framework, how can you restore to a separate db when you cant even tell which one came from where?

Answer (score 0):

You can save client-ID's in a table with timestamp and uniqueId of the data. A trigger can write this data in your client Id table. this helps you keep the track of the data the client uploaded in your database and set it to uploadonly option for sync framework. So no data will be downloaded from the server for that table. Also while downloading to the client you can have filters for data download.

you can have something like this:

syncAgent.ClientData.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.UploadOnly;